# model function including a large time loop (PYCM3)

Tags: python, theano, bayesian, sampling, pymc3

I'm trying to run a baysian calibration of a dynamic model with PYMC3.

My model function includes a large time loop, thus when the model is compiled with Theano, the RAM memory exceeds the capacity. For this problem I found how to call the function as a blackbox. However is there any other way to handle this problem without using the blackbox method ?

here an illustration :

````
with pm.Model():

    # DECLARE PRIOR
    var1 = pm.Uniform('var1', lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    var2 = pm.Uniform('var2', lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    var3 = pm.Uniform('var3', lower=0.5, upper=1.5)
    var4 = pm.Uniform('var4', lower=0.5, upper=1.5)

    theta = tt.as_tensor_variable([var1, var2, var3,var4])

    # DECLARE OBJECTIVE FUNCTION
    mu = pm.Deterministic('mu', tt.as_tensor_variable(my_model(theta,x)))
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal('sigma', 0.15)
    y_obs = pm.Normal('y_obs', mu=mu, sd=sigma, observed=data)

    step = pm.Metropolis()
    trace = pm.sample(ndraws, tune=nburn, njobs=njobs, step=step)
```

my_model is a code using mainly numpy and pandas and including large time loops such : 
for t in range(1,1000):
      x=...
````

Comment: Hi @Marty, I think it will be hard to address your question without seeing the code specifically because you are asking how to optimize a `for` loop to work efficiently within a model.  Generally, `for` loops in a model cause issues with creating too many nodes in the compute graph, because each operation that is applied to a `TensorVariable` gets added as a new node in the compute graph. E.g., possibly related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53670475/570918.

Comment: The other thing that might be important to add to your question is what exactly you would like to capture from `for` loop section. Is there something specific you want to retain from this section that is essential for downstream analysis? That would help to clarify why the blackbox approach is insufficient.

Comment: hi, thank you for your comments, I had a piece of code to illustrate the model, I whish it will make it more clear.

Comment: sorry for the delay. I don't see how I could help further. You may want to look into custom Theano ops or using a `pm.Potential` function, but I'm not totally sure that would solve it. The [PyMC Discourse site](https://discourse.pymc.io/) might get you better answers.