# "Bracket nesting level exceeded maximum" when working with large dataset in PyMC3

Tags: python, vectorization, theano, bayesian, pymc3

I have a recursive model in PyMC3 and I'm training it on about 600 timesteps. I'm getting the error

```
Exception: ('Compilation failed (return status=1): /Users/tiwalayoaina/.theano/compiledir_macOS-10.14.6-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.8.8-64/tmp1dgcmqm3/mod.cpp:30412:32: fatal error: bracket nesting level exceeded maximum of 256.         if (!PyErr_Occurred()) {.                                ^. /Users/actinidia/.theano/compiledir_macOS-10.14.6-x86_64-i386-64bit-i386-3.8.8-64/tmp1dgcmqm3/mod.cpp:30412:32: note: use -fbracket-depth=N to increase maximum nesting level. 1 error generated.. ', "FunctionGraph(MakeVector{dtype='float64'}(V0, <TensorType(float64, scalar)>, <TensorType(float64, scalar)>,..., <TensorType(float64, scalar)>, <TensorType(float64, scalar)>))")
```

It works when the data is 10 timesteps long, so I think the large dataset is causing the problem. Here's my model:

```
daily = [insert time series here; length 600]
mu = pm.Normal("mu", mu=0.01, sigma=0.07)
mu_y = pm.Normal("mu_y", mu=0, sigma=1)
sig_y = pm.HalfNormal("sig_y", sigma=1)
lamb = pm.Beta("lambda", alpha=2, beta=40)
sig_v = pm.TruncatedNormal("sig_v", mu=0.5, sigma=0.2, lower=0)
rho_j = pm.TruncatedNormal("rho_j", mu=0, sigma=0.3, lower=-1, upper=1)
mu_v = pm.HalfNormal("mu_v", sigma=1)
rho = pm.TruncatedNormal("rho", mu=0, sigma=0.3, lower=-1, upper=1)

epsSigma = tt.stack([1.0, rho, rho, 1.0]).reshape((2, 2))
eps = [pm.MvNormal("eps"+str(i), mu=np.zeros(2), cov=epsSigma, shape=2) for i in range(len(daily))]
alphabeta = pm.MvNormal("alphabeta", mu=np.zeros(2), cov=np.eye(2), shape=2)

Zv = pm.Exponential("Zv", lam=mu_v, dims="date")

Zy_mu = mu_y + rho_j * Zv
Zy = pm.Normal('Zy', mu=Zy_mu, sigma=sig_y, dims='date')

J = pm.Bernoulli("J", p=lamb, dims="date")


# this is where the problems start



V = [i for i in range(len(daily))]
V[0] = pm.TruncatedNormal("V0", mu=alphabeta[0], sigma=1, lower=0)
for t in range(1, len(V)):
    V[t] = alphabeta[0] + alphabeta[1] * V[t-1]
    V[t] = V[t] + sig_v * eps[t][1]
    V[t] = V[t] * pm.math.sqrt(10**-8 + pm.math.maximum(V[t-1], 0)) 
    V[t] = V[t] + J[t] * Zv[t]
V = pm.Normal("V", mu=tt.stack(V), sigma=0.05, dims="date")

Y = [i for i in range(len(daily))]
Y[0] = pm.Normal("YO", mu=mu, sigma=0.1)
for t in range(1, len(Y)):
    Y[t] = mu + pm.math.sqrt(10**-8 + pm.math.maximum(V[t-1], 0)) * eps[t][1] + J[t] * Zy[t]
Y_obs = pm.Normal("Y_obs", mu=tt.stack(Y), sigma=0.05, dims="date", observed=daily_obs)
```

From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53670475/bayesian-linear-regression-with-pymc3-and-a-large-dataset-bracket-nesting-leve), it seems that the issue is with the for loops used to define the length-600 vectors `V` and `Y`, but it doesn't seem to be possible to do the definitions without loops, given the nature of the recurrence relations (here they are in LaTeX for readability):

[image]

Is there a better way to define these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not getting the Exception after doing the following:

1. Instead of writing `eps` as a list of 1 dimensional arrays, define it as a 2 dimensional array

```
eps = pm.MvNormal("eps", mu=np.zeros(2), cov=epsSigma, shape=(len(daily),2))
```

2. Replace the `for` loop with `theano.scan` in the computation of `V`

```
def stepping(e,j,z,v0):
    v1 = alphabeta[0] + alphabeta[1] * v0
    v1 = v1 + sig_v * e[1]
    v1 = v1 * pm.math.sqrt(1e-8 + pm.math.maximum(v0, 0)) 
    v1 = v1 + j * z
    return v1

V0 = pm.TruncatedNormal("V0", mu=alphabeta[0], sigma=1, lower=0)
result, updates = theano.scan( fn=stepping,
                sequences=[
                    dict(input=eps, taps=[0]),
                    dict(input=J, taps=[0]),
                    dict(input=Zy, taps=[0])
                ],
                outputs_info=V0 )
V = result
```

3. Vectorize the computation of `Y`

```
Y0 = pm.Normal("YO", mu=mu, sigma=0.1)
Y = mu + pm.math.sqrt(1e-8 + pm.math.maximum(V, 0)[:-1]) * eps[1:,1] + J[1:] * Zy[1:]

Y0_obs = pm.Normal("Y0_obs", mu=Y0, sigma=0.05, dims="date", observed=daily_obs[0])
Y_obs = pm.Normal("Y_obs", mu=Y, sigma=0.05, dims="date", observed=daily_obs[1:])
```

Hope this works for you too!